# link to react route redirects to root url

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application

I have a react app that's deployed that has multiple routes for different purposes. If I want to send a link to someone with a route (`domain.com/route`) it just redirects to the root url of `domain.com`.

I think it's something to do with SPAs in general, but I can't figure out what to add or where to add. Is it an issue with DNS? My site is deployed on Digital Ocean, but my domain is from google and it redirects from a subdomain (`app.domain.com`) so maybe that's the issue.

I had a similar issue with a different react app and I was able to fix it by adding this to my `index.html`:

```
<!-- Start Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages
  // MIT License
  // https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages
  // This script checks to see if a redirect is present in the query string,
  // converts it back into the correct url and adds it to the
  // browser's history using window.history.replaceState(...),
  // which won't cause the browser to attempt to load the new url.
  // When the single page app is loaded further down in this file,
  // the correct url will be waiting in the browser's history for
  // the single page app to route accordingly.
  (function (l) {
    if (l.search[1] === "/") {
      var decoded = l.search
        .slice(1)
        .split("&")
        .map(function (s) {
          return s.replace(/~and~/g, "&");
        })
        .join("?");
      window.history.replaceState(
        null,
        null,
        l.pathname.slice(0, -1) + decoded + l.hash
      );
    }
  })(window.location);
</script>
<!-- End Single Page Apps for GitHub Pages -->
```

But it still redirects from `domain.com/route` to `app.domain.com` without the route, which makes me think it's because of the `app.`.

EDIT: However when I do `app.domain.com/route` it works, so I think the issue is with `domain.com` always redirecting to `app.domain.com` because of the way I set up my DNS. Which sort of changes the question, but I still don't know why that happens.